# Personal git repo - "Connection reset by [server] on port 22", "Remote end hung up"

Tags: ssh, git

I have an Ubuntu machine with a git repository running on a server of mine, and I'm trying to push to it. When I do, it doesn't work - here's what happens:

```
$ git push origin master
git@71.90.102.80's password:
Counting objects: 44, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 145.56 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 44 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
Connection reset by 71.90.102.80 port 22
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please note that this is not me attempting to use this server for git for the first time, I have been using this git repository for weeks, and this is the first time it hasn't worked.

All the answers I could find on this site were targeted towards github repositories, accessed through HTTPS and not SSH. They said to use a command to increase the HTTPS buffer size, which I tried, but it did not resolve the problem.

I have connected to the server with SSH and verified that it is running and that the public IP hadn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you verified you can still connect with ssh, this may be a temporary problem, e.g. the underlying ssh connection was interupted for some reason.

I suggest trying `git push origin master` again.

Comment: At first I thought - that can't be it, I restarted it! But lo and behold, it works now